# Datetime variable type deprecated in PostgreSQL 9.0.x?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp

I'm querying an external API and want to test out data inserts on a test server before moving to production.

Currently, I'm trying to execute the following statement in Postgres's shell:

```
CREATE TABLE referrals (client_id VARCHAR(36), device_id VARCHAR(100), conversion_time DATETIME, acquisition_cost MONEY);
```

but it keeps failing on `DATETIME`.

Since this doesn't work, would timestamp? If so, how do I modify timestamp's default behavior to take in preformatted dates and times?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE referrals (
  client_id text 
, device_id text 
, conversion_time timestamp
, acquisition_cost money
);
```

You don't *have* to add `without time zone`, [that is the default](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

I use the type `text` in the example instead of `varchar` with a length modifier, because that is usually the better choice. You can use `varchar(n)` of course, no problem.

[locale](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html) and [`DateStyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) settings influence how text input for `date` / `timestamp` values is interpreted. Use the functions [`to_date()` or `to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to be largely independent of local settings:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY');
```

More in the chapter [Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) of the fine manual.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the data type you're looking for is `timestamp without time zone`, so change your DDL to:

```
CREATE TABLE referrals (
   client_id VARCHAR(36), 
   device_id VARCHAR(100), 
   conversion_time TIMESTAMP without time zone, 
   acquisition_cost MONEY
);
```